# How to remove a local folder or file from Google Drive (but keep my local copy)?

Tags: google-drive, windows

I've got a folder (Projects) on my local windows 7 computer.
It's shared through Google Drive.
I want to take some of the subfolders and make them Local-only.

**I tried** going to Google Drive options (on my PC) and unchecking SubFolderName.
However, that just removed it from my local folder.

Answer (score 2):

On your PC, move (not copy) the folder (or file) to another location outside of the Google Drive Folder.

If you really want it local only, go to your Google Drive Web, [go to trash](https://drive.google.com/drive/trash) , select the folder and hit "delete forever".